# How to automatically set CSliderCtrl on instantiation

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a Dialog in MFC with a slider control (`CSliderCtrl`).
I created a new slider class, inheriting from `CSliderCtrl`, called `CMySliderCtrl`. Also, I have getter functions that gives me the desired range,

```
int get_slider_min();
int get_slider_max();
```

I want to call those getter functions on the slider instantiation. I tried overriding the Create function,

```
BOOL CMySliderCtrl::Create(DWORD dwStyle, const RECT& rect, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT nID)
```

but this is not called.. Next I tried to implement a `OnCreate` message handler but that is also not called.

How could I automatically set the slider range values with my getter functions on instantiation?

Comment: `CDialog`s do not call `Create` on their controls, rather the controls are subclassed after creation. You need to override `PreSubclassWindow` in `CMySliderCtrl` and place your initialisation code there.

Comment: @user1793036 worked! thank you very much. If you want to create an answer to close the post..